# How I can convert a decimal number to exactly 8 bit binary?

Tags: java, decimal, 8-bit

I want to write a function to convert a number to 8 bit binary String.
For example: with 20, the result I got is 10100, the expected result I want is 00010100.

```
public static int printBinaryform(int number) {
    int remainder;

    if (number <= 1) {
        System.out.print(number);
        return 0;
    }

    remainder = number % 2;
    printBinaryform(number >> 1);
    System.out.print(remainder);

    return remainder;
}

public static int encryptionNumber(int number, int key) {
    int encrrptionNumber = number ^ key;
    return encrrptionNumber;
}
```

with input is 20, I expect the output of 00010100, the actual result is 10100.

Comment: pad the output with the necessary amount of zeroes untill it reaches length of 8. Your code works simoly needs padding

Comment: I wouldn't do it recursively. Just use a loop that runs 8 times. A loop is simpler.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-pad-string

Comment: You return an `int` - it has no leading `0`s. Use a `String` instead (`String.format()` will be your friend).

Comment: Using `String.format("%08d", number)` to get a **minimum** of 8 characters `String` using `0` character leading

Answer (score 1):

You can format the integer 20 as 00010100 using this oneliner:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%08d", Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(20, 2), 10)));
```

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for. Anyways, here's how it works:

```
String str = Integer.toString(20, 2); // Turn an integer into a string consisting of numbers using base 2 (ie a string of 0:s and 1:s)

int i = Integer.parseInt(str, 10); // Parse the string assuming it is a decimal value

String.format("%08d", i); // Format the integer as a string with length 8 and leading 0:s
```

Comment: I can not use this function of Java. I have to write my own function, anyway, that is my homework: The XOR-"encryption" of that number with a specified key. All numbers in the range will be encrypted using the same key. All encryptable numbers must be 32 bit wide, the key must be exactly 8 bit wide. The four bytes of the number are then individually encrypted using the key.